# How can I safely resize a partition created by Windows To Go?

Tags: windows-8.1, partitioning, uefi, windows-to-go

Is there some way to resize a partition created by the Windows 8.1 Enterprise Widows To Go "wizard" without risking the boot system? If not, is there some other  way to deploy a Windows to Go live system (that can boot from uefi) to a smaller partition as opposed to an entire physical drive?

Comment: There are dozens of tools that exist that will allow you to create an image of your system, which also works for Windows To Go installations, and those same tools allow you when you apply the image to the desination drive indicate the size of the partition that will be created.  What does your research indicate is the first step in the process?

Comment: Windows to go does not simply provision a partition. If it did nothing but that (as you correctly intuit) I would have no problem using a garden-variety disk imager. It also does non-trivial things to the bootsector, to the best of my knowledge pointing uefi at a specific sector address where it can find the boot executable. I have found that monkeying with the partition scheme in any way after a win2go deployment results in an unbootable system,Maybe I am doing something wrong tho.